# github pages still serving deleted files

Tags: github, github-pages

My github-pages setup uses Jekyll. I have the standard setup with `.gitignore` including `_site` etc.

In addition I have placed some static html content under the root:

```
/
/index.html
/blah
/blah/index.html
```

If I visit my `*.github.com` site it serves `/index.html` correctly. If I visit `/blah/index.html` that also serves as expected.

If I then delete `/blah` and push to github however, github-pages continues to serve `/blah/index.html`. It's almost as if it hasn't detected the removal of `/blah`

How can I track down where this content is being served from and force a purge of the served pages?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The GitHub team confirmed this as a bug on their end. However, in their email response there was neither any word on whether the bug had been fixed nor steps I could take to prevent it happening in future.

So it might just be a case of contacting support in case this happens to you too

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to clear your browser cache. For example with Firefox

<kbd>Tools</kbd>
<kbd>Clear Recent History</kbd>
<kbd>Cache</kbd>